# Matching Algorithm in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given $n$ people, $k$ out of which own a car. We need to match a car for each person without a car.
Conditions:

- Each car fits $5$ people, including the driver.
- Each driver will only allow his friends to ride with him.

I am looking for an algorithm to determine if there is a match. i.e. everyone gets to ride.

I am not seeking complete answer. Hints/pointers should suffice since this is part of my college assignment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an extension of the [marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem), except that any group of n passengers needs to be friends with at least $\left \lceil \frac{n}{4}\right \rceil$ drivers.

Comment: Am I looking for a Stable Matching algorithm for a bigraph of unequal sets?

Comment: @Airwavezx Yes, I think it might be a bit like the hospital/resident problem.

Comment: Your hint helped me understand and reach the answer. The condition I used for the algo: For all subsets of drivers this condition should be met: 4 times the size of the subset should be smaller or equal to the size of its neighboring vertices.

Answer (score 0):

A linear programming formulation should do nicely, the Integrality Theorem guaranteeing that basic feasible solutions are in integers.